# JavaScript form validation: if statement regarded select tag runs even when parameter is false

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have been working on a script to check if fields are blank for my form. All of them work well, however for the birthday fields that utilise a select and option tag, when any month is chosen, the text "Choose a valid date" is still returned. I am trying to only output that text when a user chooses "Month" from the dropdown, and not let that return if a user chooses any normal month. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
function validateStudentSignUpForm() {
  var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var last = document.getElementById("last").value;
  var email1 = document.getElementById("email1").value;
  var password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
  var parentFirst = document.getElementById("parent-first").value;
  var parentLast = document.getElementById("parent-last").value;
  var childFirst = document.getElementById("child-first").value;
  var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value;
  var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
  var month1 = document.getElementById("option-month1").value;

  // First name can't be blank
  if (first == "") {
    document.getElementById("first").className = document.getElementById("first").className + " error";
    document.getElementById("firstid").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
  }

  // Last name can't be blank
  if (last == "") {
    document.getElementById("last").className = document.getElementById("last").className + " error";
    document.getElementById("lastid").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
  }

  // Email can't be blank
  if (email1 == "") {
    document.getElementById("email1").className = document.getElementById("email1").className + " error";
    document.getElementById("email1id").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
  }

  // Password can't be blank
  if (password1 == "") {
    document.getElementById("password1").className = document.getElementById("password1").className + " error";
    document.getElementById("password1id").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
  }

  // Parent first can't be blank
  if (parentFirst == "") {
    document.getElementById("parent-first").className = document.getElementById("parent-first").className + " error";
    document.getElementById("parent-firstid").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
  }

  // Parent last can't be blank
  if (parentLast == "") {
    document.getElementById("parent-last").className = document.getElementById("parent-last").className + " error";
    document.getElementById("parent-lastid").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
  }

  // Child first can't be blank
  if (childFirst == "") {
    document.getElementById("child-first").className = document.getElementById("child-first").className + " error";
    document.getElementById("child-firstid").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
  }

  // Email can't be blank
  if (email2 == "") {
    document.getElementById("email2").className = document.getElementById("email2").className + " error";
    document.getElementById("email2id").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
  }

  // Password can't be blank
  if (password2 == "") {
    document.getElementById("password2").className = document.getElementById("password2").className + " error";
    document.getElementById("password2id").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
  }

  // Month can't be default
  if (month1 = "na") {
    document.getElementById("option-month1").className = document.getElementById("option-month1").className + " error";
    document.getElementById("date1id").innerHTML = "Choose a valid date";
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two** problems:

1. You're using the value of the `option` element, not the `select`. The value of the `option` element will *always* be `"na"`. The value of the `select` will only be `"na"` if that option is the one that's selected.
2. You're using `=` instead of `==` in the comparison: `if (month1 = "na") {`. Since you only do that in that one comparison, I assume it's a typo, not a misunderstanding.

To fix it, put an `id` on the `select` and read its `value`, not the `option`'s `value`, and use `==` in the comparison.